# Django Listview for model related to user returning "No user" error

Tags: django

I'm trying to produce a list of user addresses so that a user can review and then update, delete etc...

Currently I'm using ListView with:

```
class AddressListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Address

    def get_object(self):
        return self.model.objects.get(user=self.request.user.pk)
```

with the Address model:

```
class Address(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    house_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    house_number = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    street_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    .......
```

And the url pattern:

```
....
url(
    regex=r'^address/$',
    view=views.AddressListView.as_view(),
    name='address_list'
),
...
```

However when I try to request that view I get an error "Page not found (404),  No user found matching the query"

The error is:
[image]

Comment: Please show the complete error message.

Comment: Hmm bizarrely the error is raised by UserDetailView but it has the url pattern: `url(
        regex=r'^(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)/$',
        view=views.UserDetailView.as_view(),
        name='detail'
    ),`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are writing a list view, you should override `get_queryset` (which returns a queryset of objects) instead of `get_object` (which returns a single object).

```
class AddressListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Address

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.model.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

Secondly, you are getting the 404 because the wrong view is handling the request. Django uses the first URL pattern that matches, and in this case `address/` is matched by the regex `r'^(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)/$`, so Django tries to find a user with username='address'.

You can fix this issue by moving the `address_list` URL pattern above the `detail` URL pattern - although this would prevent you viewing the `detail` page if you have a user with 'address' as the username in future. Another option is to change one or both of the regexes so that they don't clash, e.g. `r'^(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)/detail/'`.

Comment: Good point, thanks, however with those changes I still get the same error.

Comment: I don't see how you would get that error. Are you certain that the request is being handled by the view? Could there be another pattern above that is matching?

Comment: Thanks that was exactly the issue,  Django was trying to find a user with username='address'

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `.pk` from your query, as that is done automatically by Django for you.

```
return self.model.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
```

Alternatively add an `_id` to the `user`:

```
return self.model.objects.get(user_id=self.request.user.pk)
```